# Get focus area of an image

Tags: image-processing, ios7, focus

my question is about the world of images in iOs. My goal is to calculate or obtain in some way the "in focus" area of an image. I would like to know in which part of the image there is the focus. Do you know if there is a way to do that? Maybe working with contrast? I search a lot but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to divide your image into suitable regions and calculate the gradient image for each region. A sharp region will have a high gradient value(s) and a blurred will have a low.

I include an example in Python but I am sure you can convert it to a language of your choice.
I have applied the gradient calculations to an entire image but you would just replace the image `im` with your window.

Below is a montage that shows the blurring effect over the iterations and the average gradient value at each iteration. The maximum gradient value can be found at the first image and that is also the sharpest image (i.e. in focus) in this example.
[image]

[image]

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

# Load the image
original_image = cv2.imread('lena.jpg')

# Generate the smoothing kernel
kernel = cv2.getGaussianKernel(9,1)

# I played around with this value and found that there was not
# much change after 10 iteration
num_of_iter = 9

# Define containers
average_gradient = []
blurred_imlist = []

blurred_imlist.append(original_image)


# Blur the image iteratively and use the output from the previous iteration as
# input to the next
for i in range(0,num_of_iter):
    # Get the blurred image from the previous step
    im = blurred_imlist[i]

    # Calculate the gradient
    sobelx = cv2.Sobel(im,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=5)
    sobely = cv2.Sobel(im,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=5)

    abs_sobel_x = cv2.convertScaleAbs(sobelx) # converting back to uint8
    abs_sobel_y = cv2.convertScaleAbs(sobely)

    # Combine the two gradients with equal weight
    dst = cv2.addWeighted(abs_sobel_x,0.5,abs_sobel_y,0.5,0)

    # Calculate the average gradient for the image
    # I convert it to a numpy array for ease of calculation
    average_gradient.append(pl.asarray(dst).mean())



    # Blur it and this as input to the next iteration
    blurred_im = cv2.filter2D(im, -1, kernel)
    blurred_imlist.append(blurred_im)


# The index with the maximum gradient value is your in-focus image
infocus_image = pl.argmax(pl.asarray(average_gradient))
print(infocus_image)    

0
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I understood that the right way is to calculate this gradient. Do you have any idea how to do that in iOs? there are some useful classes?

Comment: You can use OpenCV to calculate the gradient. Download link is here: http://opencv.org/downloads.html and installation instructions: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html#ios-installation and tutorial: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html

Comment: Here is an example on how to calculate the gradient using OpenCV: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/sobel_derivatives/sobel_derivatives.html#sobel-derivatives

Comment: This answer demonstrate the gradient approach quite well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15840329

Comment: I've just read the tutorial and what I understood is that I have to apply this "Sobel filter" and than I will get a new black and white image in which all the edges are "highlighted". What I have to do next? Divide the image in small regions and search which one has more white pixels than the other? Do you know if I can use GPUImage framework instead of OpenCV? thank you

Comment: Yes, divide it into small regions. If GPUImage support gradient calculations, then yes but you don't have to use a framework. It's very easy (and probably very useful for you if you are learning) to calculate the gradient yourself as well.

Comment: Yes, it is but I am saying that you don't have to use a framework to calculate the gradient. You can very easily calculate the gradient that yourself.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. The Sobel filter and than the analysis of the image was the right way to solve the problem. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

An out-of-focus image of a sharp subject is identical to an in-focus image of a blurry subject, so there is no algorithm can do this in the general case.

If you assume that your in-focus area has a certain amount of micro-contrast, then you can simply find all pixels that differ from their neighbors by more than a set threshold. (Compute the pixel value minus the mean of the four neighboring pixels. This is the called the divergence of the gradient or the Laplacian.) Some video-recording systems do this to help the operator find focus.

If you have a sequence of images with varying focus, then you can compute the above for each image to find out which one has the best focus. This is how the AF-system in many compact cameras works.

Comment: OK, thank you very much for the great explanation. Do you have any idea of how to do that in iOs? Which would be the set threshold with which I can say if a "blurry pixel" or not?

Comment: The threshold value will depend on the image. A simple solution might be to pick the top one percent or something like that, but sometimes there will be out-of-foucs areas that have higher contrast than the in-focus area, so simply picking the area with the highest microcontrast won't always work. You will have to do trial and error to find what works best in your situation.

Comment: And since you're asking about iOS, I should point out that the cameras in typical iOS devices have an aperture of less than 2 mm. This means that everything will be in focus in most images. Only when the subject is extremely close to the camera will there be some out-of-focus areas in the picture.